# Proving $f(x) := \sin(ax) - \sin(bx)$ has absolute value greater or equal to 1 for some $x>0$

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

I am trying to prove that for **any** choice of reals $a$ and $b$  such that
$a \neq b $
the function $f(x) := \sin(ax) - \sin(bx)$ has $|f(x)| \geq 1$ for some $x>0$

(This is not an exercise question but something I am trying to prove for myself. Plots with Wolfram Alpha seem to indicate it might be true, and so counterexamples are very much welcome)

Here is my attempt. 
For this I wrote $f$ of 3 variables $a,b,x$. We find that value of $x_0$ 
for which $f$ attains a maximum and minimum and then show that $|f(x_0)|$
greater than 1.

$g(a,b,x)=f(x)$ and then zeroing the gradient. (pending the 2nd derivative test)

$f_a = x \cos(ax)$

$f_b = -x \cos(bx)$

$f_x = a\cos(ax) - b\cos(bx)$

Since the point of minima/maxima are conjectured $x>0$ , this means $\cos(ax)$ and $\cos(bx)$ are both zero
and the third equation is redundant.

If $a$ and $b$ are rational then obviously we can find such an $x$.
But when one of them is irrational, I don't know how I would prove this.

Another attempt was using the $\sin(u)-\sin(v)$ product formula, but that 
led nowhere too.

Any pointers?

Comment: Simple counterexample: $a=b=0$.

Comment: Ah yes. I should have added non-zero condition :-D Please see edit.

Comment: In general, just $a = b$ is a counterexample. They have to be distinct, since we would have $f(x) = \sin ax -\sin ax \equiv 0$.

Comment: Good point. Please see edit.

Comment: Note that a common factor $\neq0$ for $a$ and $b$ doesn't change the range, so you can fix $a=1$

Comment: If $a\ne b\ne 0,$ we set $\sin ax=1\implies x=\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{2a}$ We need to find $\sin bx<0$ $$ \implies (2m-1)\pi< \frac{b(4n+1)\pi}{2a}<2m\pi \iff 2a(2m-1)<b(4n+1)<4am$$  Now,we need to show the existence such $m,n$

Comment: You still need $\neq 0$ even with the condition $a\neq b$, because with $a=0$ you'll get just $\cos bx$ which obviously never goes above $1$.

Comment: Ok I have edited again. I must be more careful with my posts in future :D Thank you for the comment.

Comment: BTW, since $a$ and $b$ are parameters, you don't want to derive for them (you want to prove that for *any* $a$,$b$ — apart from pathological cases — you get $\lvert f(x)\rvert>1$ for some $x$, not just that there are such values).

Comment: Ah very good point ! That was an incorrect line of thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a=b$, then $f(x)=0$. If $a=0$ or $b=0$ then we have just a single sine function and hence $|f(x)|\le 1$ for all $x$. Therefore these cases must be excluded.

If $a=-b$, we have $f(x)=2\sin (ax)$, hence $f(\frac{\pi}{2a})=2$ and we are done. We may therefore assume that 
$$\tag1a,b,a+b,a-b\text{ are nonzero.}$$
Note that $$\tag2\sin (ax)-\sin (bx)=2\cos{\left(\frac{a+b}2x\right)}\sin\left(\frac{a-b}2x\right).$$
The cosine is $\pm1$ at $x\in \frac{2k\pi}{a+b}\mathbb Z$. Thus it is sufficient to find $k\in\mathbb Z$ with
$$\tag3 \left|\sin\frac{(a-b)k\pi}{a+b}\right|>\frac12.$$
For which $c\in\mathbb R$ can we conclude that there exists $k\in\mathbb Z$ with $|\sin( ck\pi)|>\frac12$? Since $|\sin(ck\pi)|=|\sin((c+1)k\pi)|$, we may restrict to the case $c\in[0,1)$.
And since $|\sin((1-c)k\pi)|=|\sin(ck\pi)|$, we can restrict further to $c\in[0,\frac12]$. If $\frac16<c\le \frac12$, we succeed by choosing $k=1$.
If $0<c\le\frac16$, let $k=\lceil\frac1{6c}\rceil$, i.e. we have $\frac16<kc\le\frac16+c\le \frac13$ and thus obtain $\sin(ck\pi)>\frac12$. 
Allowing arbitrary $c\in\mathbb R$ again, we therefore conclude that there exists $k\in\mathbb Z$ with $|\sin(ck\pi)|>\frac12$ unless $c$ is not an integer.
Back to our original problem, we can thus show the existence of $x$ with $|f(x)|>1$ unless $c:=\frac{a-b}{a+b}$ is an integer. 
Note that $c\notin\{-1,0,1\}$ because of $(1)$.
Therefore $\left|\frac{\pi}{2c}\right|\le\frac\pi 4 3$ and 
$$f\left(\frac{\pi}{a-b}\right)=2\cos \frac{\pi}{2c}\sin\frac\pi2\ge2\cos\frac\pi4=\sqrt2>1. $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

For $x_k=\pi/2a + 2*k\pi/a $, $\sin(ax_k) =1$ You "just" have to prove that for a certain $x_k$ $\sin(bx_k)$ is inferior than 0.

By this method, you could also prove a greater result : There exists $x$ where $f(x)>A$ for every $A<2$